# I am getting a - Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched around for this answer but can not find one to get this resolved. I am getting a error on a page of my wordpress theme. I am editing the site on a local server using XAMPP.

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\solar\wp-content\plugins\bdevs-element\widgets\faq\faq-widget.php on line 687

When opening the faq-widget.php file in Visual Studio this is line 687

```
$tab_small_image = $settings['tab_small_image']['url'];
```

I will also provide a couple lines before and after to give a better idea of the section.

```
// img small
    $tab_small_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( !empty($settings['tab_small_image']['id']), !empty($settings['tab_big_image_size']) );
    if ( ! $tab_small_image ) {
        $tab_small_image = $settings['tab_small_image']['url'];
    }
```

I have also attached the screenshot of the page and the code to help clearly show what I am seeing.

[The webpage I am seeing this on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iWX4.jpg)

[More code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LaLK.jpg)

Thank you for the help in advance! It is much much appreciated!

Comment: Either `$settings` or `$settings['tab_small_image']` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an image size of an image, and that size does not exist. The size is called `tab_small_image`.
You should try installing a plugin which can be found with `Regenerate Thumbnails`. That way the missing image size could be added.

But if you just want to get rid of the error:

It tells you that you are trying to access an array element which does not exist. The variable `tab_small_image` has a value of `null`.
So we can avoid accessing the array position with adding another condition to the `if` clause. We check if it is defined and if it is not empty.

```
// img small
$tab_small_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( !empty($settings['tab_small_image']['id']), !empty($settings['tab_big_image_size']) );
if ( $tab_small_image && !empty( $tab_small_image ) {
    $tab_small_image = $settings['tab_small_image']['url'];
}
```

There should be no more error. Now you don't try to access an array value of an variable that is null.